# Object instantiation in index file is not working

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to structure my Slim application like

```
app
  index.php
  config
  lib
  vendor
  assets
  templates
sys
 Slim
```

and my index.php looks like

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}

if (!defined('ROOT_DIR')) {
    define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
}

if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
    ini_set('include_path', ROOT_DIR . DS . 'sys' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
}



require '/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
```

But can't instanciate Slime object. What I am doing here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your path to "require '/Slim/Slim.php'" is wrong.

If you want to load Slim.php from index.php then you need to go one step up (to parent folder) then enter sys directory then Slim and Slim.php is located there. It is important to understand this.

So this should work:

```
require '../sys/Slim/Slim.php';
```

Let's understand code:

- '..' means move to parent folder. In your case that is "app"
- '/sys' means enter sys directory
- '/Slim' we are now in slim directory
- 'Slim.php' and finally we tell include Slim.php file